# Routing to different mvc-applications

Tags: routes, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a question.
Is it possible to have one index-page with hyperlinks to different mvc-applications?

How would it be implemented?

So on my homepage I would have something like this:

```
=> applications
   => App1
   => App2
   => App3
```

The applications are all three different MVC-applications.

Comment: Use an anchor tag. What do you mean?

Comment: What I mean is that I have one login-page. After you have successfully logged in, you are given an index-page with links to the different MVC Application that you can use.

Comment: Typically, you make a *single* application with authentication and then use multiple [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to organize the application into different sections. By splitting your application into 4 applications, you are making authentication, deployment, and server setup unnecessarily complex. If you don't have a choice, then you are in for an uphill battle to get this working, and there is likely more than a single question involved. But if you do have a choice, choose a single application, not 4.

Comment: @NightOwl888: so for each application we should create an area in our MVC-project? Wouldn't that make a huge solution if we would have lets say 20applications that should be available via that login?

Comment: @BartSchelkens - No, it would make a small solution with exactly 1 MVC project that has an area for each of your 20 so-called "applications". This makes the login much easier to implement, makes deployment much easier, and makes the web server easier to configure because you are left with just 1 application to maintain.

Comment: Of course, there are edge cases where your solution makes sense (integrating multiple 3rd party web sites, for example), but you must weigh the tradeoff of doing all of the extra work to integrate a 3rd party solution against the cost of doing it all yourself from scratch. But if you are doing it all from scratch there is little point in splitting your one MVC project into 20 MVC projects, especially if they share the same login.

Comment: @NightOwl888: If i'm using the membership of ASP.Net MVC, that would mean I would have to create reles for each application and assign that to a user? Something like : App1Reader, App1Admin, App2Reader, App2Admin? Since not all users will have the same rights to the applications.

Comment: Possibly. The roles are not per Area. When the user signs in, all of their roles are applied to the signed in user - this is site wide. But not every Area needs to use the same roles. You could potentially make roles for each Area if that is what your requirements dictate. You could alternatively use [claims](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/26/using-claims-based-authorization-in-mvc-and-web-api/) to handle permissions-based access.